# SailsJS: set the status code on an error coming from lifecycle callbacks

Tags: sails.js

I am using the lifecycle callbacks to validate user authorization to change specific attributes.

```
beforeUpdate: function (valuesToUpdate, cb) {

   //details of how authorized is getting set have been omitted
   if(!authorized) return cb("Unauthorized!");
   cb();
}
```

When the user is not authorized I receive a `400 Bad Request` error

```
{
    msg: "Unauthorized!"
}
```

I'd like to return a `403 Forbidden`. Is there anyway in SailsJS to control the error returned more precisely?

**Update**: I am using sails v0.10.5

Comment: What version of sails are you using?

Comment: I am suspicious that it might be my controller logic that is returning the badRequest, however my debugger doesn't hit that line. I plan to double check the observed behavior later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send an instance of WLValidationError to be sent as validation error

```
//in api/models/User.js
function validationError(invalidAttributes, status, message) {
  var WLValidationError = require('../../node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLValidationError.js');
  return new WLValidationError({
      invalidAttributes: invalidAttributes,
      status: status,
      message: message
    }
  );
}
var User = {
  attributes: {
    //...
  },
  ownValidate:: function (values, update, cb) {
    //example of not allowed param on update
    //if it is an update then do not allow email param
    if (update && values.email) {
      return cb(validationError({
        email: [
          {
            message: 'Email is not allowed for updates.'
          }
        ]
      }, 403 /*status*/));
    }
    sails.models['user'].findOne(values.email).exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      if (user) {
        return cb(validationError({
          email: [
            {
              value: values.email,
              rule: 'E_UNIQUE'
              /* unique validation message is left for the default one here */
            }
          ]
        }, 409));
      }
    });
  },
  beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    return sails.models['user'].ownValidate(values, false, cb);
  },
  beforeUpdate: function (values, cb) {
    return sails.models['user'].ownValidate(values, true, cb);
  }
}
```

For more info [check this](http://gadelkareem.com/2014/12/12/custom-validation-messages-for-sails-js/)

Comment: I know this is an old post but if you would update your line with the `400 /*status*/` to a 403 and include the `beforeUpdate` (like in the link you posted) then I'd mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: added the changes!